# Converting a data address offset to the equivalent struct in a C++ module

Tags: ida, decompilation, c++, injection

I have an offset to a property within a player class that I need to access data from. It's made of a specific struct that I have already assembled. IDA reports the accessing offset as so:

```
v32 = ( v3 + 280 ) // v3 is the player in this case
```

I want to convert this to the correct struct within my own C++ module so I can read a specific property of that struct. I can easily get the base address of the players but whenever I get the property it doesn't come out correct.

I have tried something of the following:

```
playerData* lpData = reinterpret_cast<playerData*>((int)n_GetLocalPlayer() + 280);
```

But the struct isn't correct.

There is NO doubt that the base address or offset are correct, as the function I reversed in IDA was short and well commented. I just need help casting it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So silly me, the function `n_GetLocalPlayer()` needed to be dereferenced and then the result from the offset dereferenced again. It works now. Here's the format:

```
playerData* lpData = reinterpret_cast<playerData*>((*((DWORD *)n_GetLocalPlayer() + 280)));
```